# Flutter project fails to build on iOS Simulator (Duplicate symbol error)

Tags: ios, flutter, build, simulator, duplicate-symbol

I have been getting this error whenever I try to build my flutter project on an iOS Simulator. Sometimes it works just fine after deleting the Podfiles from the ios folder, and also using the "flutter pub cache repair" and "flutter clean" commands in the terminal. I can't seem to figure out the problem and find a permanent solution.

```
Xcode build done.                                            3.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FLAnimatedImageView._currentFrameIndex' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FLAnimatedImageView' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FLAnimatedImageView' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FLAnimatedImageView._accumulator' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FLAnimatedImageView._loopCountdown' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FLAnimatedImageView._displayLink' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FLAnimatedImageView._loopCompletionBlock' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FLAnimatedImageView._shouldAnimate' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FLAnimatedImageView._debug_delegate' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FLAnimatedImageView._currentFrame' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FLAnimatedImageView._needsDisplayWhenImageBecomesAvailable' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FLAnimatedImageView._animatedImage' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FLAnimatedImageView._runLoopMode' in:
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView 3.o
        /Users/talalalaseeri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bftdmqcmgdiohxcufhejdtlprqft/Build/Intermediates.no
        index/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FLAnimatedImage.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLAnimatedImageView.o
    ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```